# Problem with binding a Xamarin Forms iOS library with objective Sharpie

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, objective-sharpie

I am currently trying to bind the following iOS SDK to use it in a Xamarin project:
http://github.com/emartech/ios-emarsys-sdk

Android worked, but with iOS I have some issues.

What I have done so far:

1. I copied the source files into a Static Library Project, build with iOS Simulator and iOS Device was successful (arm64 and x86_64)
2. I combined the two a files to a Fat Library.
3. I run objective sharpie to generate the ApiDefinitions.

My problem now is, that the .a files are quite small (only 4kb each) and the ApiDefinition only have 1 header (the default one that was automatically created from the Static Library). All other headers are missing.

Do I have to add them somewhere explicitly? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to copy the files from the subfolders to the main folder but without success.

Comment: Did you add the .a files to your binding project? You can refer to the official document ([Walkthrough: Binding an iOS Objective-C Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows#including-the-static-library-in-the-binding-project)) for steps.

Comment: Yes, I followed this steps and added the a file. But the a file is too small and doesn’t contain all .h files.

Comment: Have you copied the .h file to the new static library, refer to this step:[add the source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows#:~:text=we%20need%20to-,add%20the%20source,-from%20the%20InfColorPicker)